# Is there a way to parameterize the number of decimals of SSRS reports?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, reporting-services

In my work we generate stored procedures for each report of our application and then we generate their corresponding RDL in Visual Studio and store them in SQL Server Reporting Services. The data format is styled in each of the reports. My research consists in finding a way that the number of decimal places can be defined in one place and thereafter replicated in each report.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes store the format in the dataset query if I have different measures in the same column so the dataset might look like this...

```
Name     Measure      Amount     formatString
Dave     Age          42         'f0'
Dave     Salary       55000      'c2'
Dave     pcTimeAsleep 0.5123     'p2'
```

Then in the report, I set the format to Fields!formaString.Value

The output in a matrix would then look like

```
Name   Age    Salary       Time caught asleep
Dave   42     £55,000.00   51.23%
```

You could do a similar thing tha applies to the entire set of reports I guess. If you only needed a single format string you could store that and add a shared dataset that retrives the format strings.